# Strange test-case result in CodeWars Kata

Tags: python

I need some help solving a CodeWars Kata that I'm kind of stuck with. For some reason I am receiving a False in one of the test-cases and I can't find the real reason behind it.

The instructions are to validate a `string(ping)`. The requirements are that the string needs to have the length of 4 **or** 6 and can only consist of digits.

This is my code:

```
def validate_pin(pin): 
    
    if (len(pin) != 4 or len(pin) != 6):
        return False
    print(pin.isdigit())
    if(pin.isdigit()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It passes 9/10 tests. This is the input / output for the failed test:

> I recieve False on validate_pin('1234'):
>
> > Wrong output for '1234': False should equal True

Comment: `if (len(pin) != 4 or len(pin) != 6):` - think harder about what that line means.

Comment: omg... that's what assembling IKEA furniture does to your head... God I'm stupid. Sorry for the idiotic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) != 6):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the length of a digit. Usually length of string or sequence is performed.
May be a following sequence of the below example will help you to understand.

```
>>>
>>> len(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
>>> len('4')
1
>>> len('abc')
3
>>> len([1,2,'a'])
3
>>>
```